# The identity map on a tangent space

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

If $X$ is a smooth manifold and $I : X \rightarrow X$ is the identity map on $X$ (with the same smooth structure on both sides) then I can show that $dI_x : T_x X \rightarrow T_x X$ is the identity map on the tangent space $T_x X$ of $X$ at some point $x \in X$. Here $dI_x$ is the differential of $I$ at the point x.

Is the converse of this statement also true? That is if I have a map $f : X \rightarrow X$ such that $f(x)=x $ for some $x \in X$ and $df_x : T_x X \rightarrow T_x X$ is the identity map on $T_x X$ then $f$ is the identity map?

For example, if I have a map $f : X \rightarrow X$ that is identity restricted to some open subset $U$ of $X$ then $T_x X = T_x U$ for $x\in U$ so $df_x$ is the identity map, but $f$ need not be. Is that right?

Thanks!

Comment: The only way rhat $df_x$ is the identity is if $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, for otherwise the domain and codomain of the linear map $df_x$ are not the same!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez In the question it says "for *some* $x\in X$".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez is it not enough just that  $f(x)=x$ for that particular so that the domain and codomain of $df_x$ is the same? Is $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in X$ necessary? The map $df_x$ depends only on the point $x$ right? Have I missed something?

Comment: @Raisa Not missing anything, your question does make sense (even though the answer to it is negative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\;x\mapsto\sin x$. We have $f(0)=0$, and $df_0=id$. However, $f$ is not the identity, not even on some neighborhood of $0$.