# Question on tangent spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138943/the-identity-map-on-a-tangent-space) question, if I also had that $f$ were a diffeomorphism and $f^k = I$ for some positive integer $k$ would it make a difference to the answer being in the negative? Here, by $f^k$ I mean $f$ composed with itself $k$ time.

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear about your question, you're asking, given that $df_x:T_xX \to T_xX$ is the identity map for some $x \in X$, and given that $f^k=I$ for some $k$, is $f$ necessarily the identity map?  Is that correct?

Comment: @AustinC yes that is correct

Comment: Without the restriction that $df_x$ be the identity map for some $x \in X$, the map $f:S^2 \to S^2$ given by $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2},\phi)$ would do the trick.  This is rotation about the $z$-axis by a quarter turn, so it has two fixed points, and $f^4=I$.  Unfortunately, the differential is nowhere the identity.

Comment: Right. This is good if I didn't have that restriction. But I want to see what happens with it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is a connected smooth manifold and $f$ is a diffeomorphism of $M$ such that $f^k$ is the identity for some $k$, and there exists a point $x \in M$ such that $f(x) = x$ and $df_x$ is the identity, then $f$ is the identity.

Proof: Equip $M$ with any Riemannian metric $g$, and then consider the metric
$$
  \tilde{g}(v, w) = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} g\Big((df)^jv, (df)^jw \Big). 
$$
The point is that since $f^k$ is the identity, $f$ acts as an isometry on $M$ equipped with the metric $\tilde{g}$.

But for isometries $f$ the condition $f(x) = x$ and $df_x = I$ imply that $f$ is the identity. (One can easily check that the set of points $y$ on which $f(y) = y$ and $df_y = I$ is both open and closed.)

Comment: can you please tell me what $(df)^j$ means?

Comment: Presumably $df$ composed with itself $j$ times, in accordance with your notation $f^k$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks mollyerin and AustinC.